# Test if function of object has been called inside another function in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My code looks somewhat like this :

```
Class A :{
    Object foo = new foo;
    function (){
        ...
        let var = this.foo.bar()
        ...
}
```

And I would like to test with jest that foo.bar() has been called. I've tried with

```
barSpy = jest.spyOn(function, 'foo.bar');
```

but it doesn't work, can someone guide me toward the good syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for `jest.spyOn` are the object that contains the function you want to spy on, and the name of the function to spy on (see: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname). It's a little hard to say with the given syntax above, but if `foo` is available as a property on an instance of `A` (for this example let's say your instance is called `a`), then `a.foo` is the object, and `'bar'` is the name of the function.

Here's some code to better illustrate:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = new foo();
    }

    function myFunction() {
        ...
        this.foo.bar();
        ....
    }
}

...

let a = new A();
let barSpy = jest.spyOn(a.foo, 'bar');
```